# What determined who would be on the front lines of a large infantry engagement?

Tags: military, middle-ages, europe, infantry

In Ancient and Middle Aged European Armies, what decided whether a soldier was at the front lines or just in the normal center-back? Was it a status symbol or honor to be in the front lines?

Please specify the country and age that this was in your answer. Anywhere where there were large scale battles.

I'm surprised about the little of information I can find on the subject and I'm quite curious what were the factors if there were any.

In essence I'm trying to figure out when you look at any kind of infantry regiment charging into battle who and what determined who was at the front of the lines.

Comment: You've added tags for when (although the middle-ages seems a little wide) but not where in the world.

Comment: Apologies ill be a bit more specific

Comment: Please narrow the scope - there are almost no questions that can be meaningfully answered between BCE & 11th century.  The role of infantry changes significantly several times. The role of cavalry changes significantly when the stirrup is introduced.  Trying to discuss these all in the same answer is like trying to discuss infantry pre and post gunpowder.

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate status: even though the time period here is too wide, it doesn't stray into Napoleonic/musketry ages in any way. I suspect, however, @Azurry, you'll need to make this explicit in the post and to focus in on a specific country and timeframe as well.

Comment: I assume you're talking pre-firearms, and here the answer is pretty simple. Fighting hand-to-hand is mind-bogglingly **exhausting**. Even if your first line does not suffer *any* losses, it will become winded in basically no time at all, and will need to be replaced. We are talking *minutes* here, and not many of those either, and you will *have* to replace the first rank, or lose them altogether. Which means, being in the first rank wasn't THAT much of an issue, because you wouldn't be there for long... [Lindybeige going on about this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=croWDsDhgPo).

Comment: (ctd.) This changed over time as being in the front line became more lethal, giving birth to things like the [Doppelsöldner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppels%C3%B6ldner). -- Lindybeige's video also points out one overarching important thing, though, true especially for ancient and early medieval times: *We don't really know.*

Comment: @DevSolar: Lindybeige in that video is talking about *maniple swap* - not at all "*who fights on the front line?*". An entirely different question. Each maniple and/or century still must decide, somehow, the assignment of each member to a rank and file of the formation.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Errr.... what is the maniple swap other than "relieving the front line"? Of course, if ypu are talking about a combined unit, with swordsmen front and piles second, you can't really swap them around. But then, "being swordmen" makes you first line...

Comment: @DevSolar: Seriously?! Maniple swap is the maneuvring on the battlefield of Roman units the size of a modern company or platoon, each of which was a pair of tight rectangular formations (centuries) of 6x10 (or perhaps 10x6) men. Each of these would perforce have had a "*front rank*". If the question is about how generals maneuvred their tactical units, rather than how individual tactical units selected a "*front line*" then it is trivial: Answer: However the general thought best to attempt winning.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Then we are talking about different things, and I might have been using the wrong term (in which case I am sorry). I was referring to (velites) giving way to the hastati giving way to the principes giving way to the triarii. And this isn't just about the Roman legions; the basic priciple is, you keep the same people fighting in the front line only if you are absolutely positively sacrificing them, and no good general would do that unless forced by dire circumstances. Fighting in the front row was not "till death", it was "till swapped".